# Xamarin Forms App Crashes if iPad is locked, while running in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.forms app that crashes when I lock the iPad that it is running on.  I had selected remote notifications and background fetch to cause this behavior.  However, after the app is installed on the ipad, and not being run through visual studio, the app works normally.

I get this error in the debug

> Failed to Stop app:  An error occured on client IDB4110756 while
>   executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.11.0.756/stop-app

If anyone can think of anything, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use latest version of Xcode, Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin forms.

That should solve it. Also debug on what happens when `OnResume()` `OnPause()` life cycle events.